# API call works in a java project but not when called inside an Android application

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api

We are trying to use the Google Places API to find nearby places and have that working when run simply as a java project. However, running the same piece of code under an onClick() function for a button inside an android application causes our JSON string returned from Google to be empty. Hardcoded GPS coordinates were used for both.

Why is that?

This is the error shown when trying to grab the JSON data

```
05-14 00:54:12.828: E/PlacesService(8677): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-14 00:54:12.828: E/PlacesService(8677):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
05-14 00:54:12.828: E/PlacesService(8677):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
```

This is where the API call is made:

```
private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String place) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder(
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

    if (place.equals("")) {
        urlString.append("&location=");
           urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
           urlString.append(",");
           urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
           urlString.append("&radius=1000");
           // urlString.append("&types="+place);
           urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);

    } else {
        urlString.append("?types=" + "bar" + "|" + "night_club");
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        urlString.append("&radius=1000");
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    }
    return urlString.toString();
}

protected String getJSON(String url) {
    return getUrlContents(url);
}

private String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();
}
```

Here is how we call those methods above to grab the JSON string:

```
    String urlString = makeUrl(32.8400, -117.2769 placeSpacification);
    String json = getJSON(urlString);
```

This is our AndroidManifest.xml. We have included the necessary Location and Internet permissions.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testapp.ListViewAndroidExample"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but it's recommended (required in later versions) to do network operations on a background thread, such as using an AsyncTask.  That would be a good thing to do anyway even if it doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: How does that work? Do you know of any tutorials using Asynctask?

Answer (score 0):

Hey add Aquery jar to your project and try following code .

```
latitude =18 ;
longitude = 50 ;
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    builder.append("location="+latitude+","+longitude);
    builder.append("&radius=100");
    builder.append("&sensor=true");
    builder.append("&types="+type);
    builder.append("&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    String url = builder.toString();

 aQuery.progress(progressDialog).ajax(url, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>(){

        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject object,
                AjaxStatus status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.callback(url, object, status);

            //System.out.println("objectttt ====  "+object);

            JSONArray jsonArray;

            try {

                jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("results");
                for(int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    String placeName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String placeAddress= jsonObject.getString("vicinity");
                    String image=jsonObject.getString("icon");

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    JSONObject jsonObject3 =jsonObject2.getJSONObject("location");

                    for(int i=0 ;i<jsonObject3.length();i++)
                    {
                        PlaceLatitude =jsonObject3.getDouble("lat");
                        PlaceLongitude =jsonObject3.getDouble("lng");

                    }

                    try 
                    {
                      imgURL= new URL(image);

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    arrPlaces.add(placeName);
                    arrPlaceImage.add(imgURL);
                    arrPlaceAddress.add(placeAddress);
                    arrPlaceLatitude.add(PlaceLatitude);
                    arrPlaceLogitude.add(PlaceLongitude);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```